# HOw to link table to @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have program in mvc which fetch data from controller and then display in view.It makes dynamic table with data in it. Inside it there is a link "SEE DETAILS", but instead of a single link i want to make whole table as a link like :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("SEE DETAILS", "AppDetail", new { @id = item.id, appnameformp = item.AppNameForMP }, new { @style = "color:#C55000;font-size: 11px;text-decoration:none;" })
```

but i don't know how to do it...Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
 <div class="grid_9.5 alpha">
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <div class="grid_4 alpha box_shadow" id="featured-subbillboard" style="margin-bottom:10px;"   >
               <table>
                    <tr >
                    <td><img height="140" width="130" src=@item.imgfile />
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="table">
                        <h1  class="heading1" style="margin-top:10px; line-height: .4em;">@item.AppNameForMP </h1>
                        <h2 class="heading2">@item.DevName </h2>
                        <br />
                        <p class="para">
                        @if (item.AppDesc.Length > 50)
                            {@item.AppDesc.Remove(@item.AppDesc.Length -50)} 
                        else
                            { @item.AppDesc}
                        </p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("SEE DETAILS", "AppDetail", new { @id = item.id, appnameformp = item.AppNameForMP }, new { @style = "color:#C55000;font-size: 11px;text-decoration:none;" })
                     </td>

                     </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
         }
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular anchor tag, and use `@Url.Action()` to get the href:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AppDetail")">
    <!-- table here -->
</a>
```

Also, note that while block-level links are now supported in HTML5, browser support and even implementation is not consistent. Some will handle linking the whole table well, while others will do all kinds of weird stuff. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...I tried to use   <a href="@Url.Action("SEE DETAILS", "AppDetail", new { @id = item.id, appnameformp = item.AppNameForMP })"> but its making an url : http://localhost:54971/en-us/AppDetail/SEE%20DETAILS/8?appnameformp=app1 instead of http://localhost:54971/en-us/Marketplace/AppDetail/8?appnameformp=app1

Comment: Because that's not the definition of `Url.Action`. It's first parameter is the action, and the second parameter is the controller or a `RouteDataDictionary`. You don't specify the link text, i.e. "SEE DETAILS", because this doesn't return a full link tag, just the URL. You're telling it to get the URL for the "SEE DETAILS" action in `AppDetailsController`, which is obviously non-existent.

Comment: sorry, i didn't noticed it...now i corrected and works fine...thanks a ton